# Heavy compression algorithms that consume lot of resources?

Tags: compression

What compression algorithms allow to heavily lossless compress the data due to the large (potentially unlimited) consumption of computational resources?

Answer (score 2):

You can find in [Mark Mahoney's benchmarks](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html) many lossless compression algorithms that are unconstrained by execution time or memory resources. The current winner is [cmix](http://www.byronknoll.com/cmix.html). It compresses at 1300 to 1600 bytes per second (as opposed to tens to hundreds of *megabytes* per second with common lossless compressors), using 20 to 30 GB of RAM.